# Typescript types for wordpress Gutenberg using the useSelect hook getting the core/editor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to use typescript in development with wordpress and the Gutenberg editor. I am trying to use the `useSelect()` hook but I get a type error trying to use an attached function to the `core/editor`. So here is an example of the issue I am having:

```
const featured = useSelect(
  (select) =>
    select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')[
      '_projects_featured'
    ],
  []
)
```

And I get the following Error:

> Property 'getEditedPostAttribute' does not exist on type 'never'.

I am assuming because the proper type is not being applied because I get the same error no matter what I try to get from `select('core/editor')`. But I'm not sure what type I am supposed to apply to it.  I can just set the selected `core/editor` to `any` like:

```
const editor: any = useSelect((select) => select('core/editor'))
const postAttribute = editor.getEditedPostAttribute()
```

But this obviously defeats the purpose of using typescript.

There is not a lot of information out there about development with wordpress and typescript and there is no official Wordpress typescript documentation. I have added a bunch of typings I will post a few of them from my `package.json`.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/wordpress__components": "^19.10.5",
  "@types/wordpress__core-data": "^2.4.5",
  "@types/wordpress__data": "^6.0.1",
  "@types/wordpress__edit-post": "^4.0.1",
  "@types/wordpress__editor": "^11.0.0",
  "@types/wordpress__element": "^2.14.1",
  "@types/wordpress__plugins": "^3.0.0",
  "@wordpress/data": "^8.0.0",
  "@wordpress/edit-post": "^7.0.0",
  "@wordpress/plugins": "^5.0.0"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not sure if using typescript for development with Wordpress Gutenberg is a good Idea or not.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that `useSelect()` is imported at the start of your script:

```js
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

const featured = useSelect(...);
```

If the issue is still present, check the post type you are querying has the given meta key registered. Note: meta keys that are prefixed with an underscore, like `_projects_featured` are a [private/hidden custom field](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/managing-post-metadata/#hidden-custom-fields) and will not appear within the post edit - this could be the potential issue with this particular meta field. The syntax of your `const featured = useSelect(...)` is fine, so another potential issue could be that the select is not yet resolved when you use it.